# how to notify another process when file lock is released?

Tags: linux, ipc, file-locking, flock, fcntl

I have a small application consisting of two process.

Process A downloads a file. Process B uses the downloaded file.

When Process A downloads a file, it acquires file lock on it. Process B keep checking whether the file being downloaded is locked or not.

Once the downloading is completed, Process A releases file lock and the downloaded file is ready to use by Process B.

In Process B, I have dedicated thread which checks if the lock is released.

I want to avoid the loop of continuous file-lock check. Is there a way similar to `select` or `poll` system call using which Process B gets notifies about the file lock getting released ?

I have explored man pages of fcntl, flock but I did not find a way to do it.

Comment: There is probably a way to do it using inotify. But I'm not completely familiar with inotify. You can also accomplish this with unix sockets: process A can open an AF_UNIX socket listening on abstract name. Any process B (even multiple) can connect to the socket if it knows the abstract name. When Process A is done, it can then close each acquired connection. Process B's file descriptor to the connected socket will become readable; when reading from the socket, an error will be returned indicating EOF. This would be your notification that process A is done.

Comment: Can process B just block waiting to acquire the lock or does it have other things it needs to do in the meantime? (If the latter, maybe a thread dedicated to waiting for the lock?)

Comment: The latter case. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using IPC:
[Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)
Process A after finishing download tells to B it is finished.

Or you can use a network connection to inform B, but I would not suggest it.